# Code Sharing between React and React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, types

i am trying to find a good way to share codes between projects like Types and Redux Stores. The best 3 methods i've seen is:

1. Npm package - creating a private package.

- But if i wanted to change something in the npm package while developing, how would i do that?

2. Git Submodules

- I've seen that this way can have some side effects.

3. Copy/Paste

- The way i am doing now xD .. But really horrible way,  cause i have to change the same stuff several times and can forget what i've changed..

How would u resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deploying straight to npmjs.com you can use the [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link) cli to install your package locally and then when you need to make changes during development, they will be automatically updated to your projects

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Would i have to link it for every environment or just once?

Comment: @Muhaki you'd have to link it for every environment you use it in, but you could use a hosted git repo to have each "copy" up to date

Comment: Thanks, i've seen a way to do it with npm linking and git submodules, where you will have a main repo with projects as submodules, so you work on that one, but push to the projects itself. It seems pretty interesting, and will investigate further!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case for a monorepo, with a solution like [NX](https://nx.dev/) or [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna)

You have one repository that contains multiple apps, and the common code they share. This makes it trivial to update shared code because it's only ever in one place.

In NX, for instance, you have a directory structure like:

```
apps/
  website/ (React app)
  mobile-app/ (React native app)
  backend/ (Node.js Express app)
libs/
  common-utils/
  fancy-types/
  constants/
```

And if you want something from a shared lib, you just:

```
import { foo } from '@mymonoreponame/common-utils'
```

It is a big change, so if you are wanting to keep those projects in separate repositories, this solution isn't going to help you. But after struggling with similar issues, the switch to a NX monorepo really helped my workflow.

Comment: I did actually look at NX and liked it. But the issue i had with it was when i want to deploy a project, i have to install all the unnecassery dependencies also.

Comment: That's technically true, but isn't so bad, really. Webpack will only package up what each app/lib actually uses. So it's not like unused stuff is actually included in any production code.

Comment: Thanks, i really wish that NX could do the job done. But another problem will be with CI/CD, i trigger build at the master branch to production, it will destroy that idea, cause if i make changes to only backend and push that one, it will also trigger for everything else :/ .

Comment: @Muhaki I haven't set this up this yet, but there is supposed to some tooling for that as well: https://nx.dev/latest/react/guides/ci/distributed-builds. NX can detect what libs/apps are affected by a specific change, and CI can be configured to run only those